# Post Construct is not called

Tags: java, liferay, icefaces-3, postconstruct

I wrote a managed bean with post construct method (using @PostContruct), but the method is not being called. I'm using liferay liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3 with Jboss 7.1.1, and Icefaces 3.0. Can someone help me figure this out?

```
    @SessionScoped
    @ManagedBean
    public class DetalleVaPortletBean extends BackingPortletUI {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7127465434575796794L;

        public DetalleVaPortletBean() {
            try {
                System.out.println(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                error(e);
            }
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void postConstruct(){
            adicionarPortletPrincipal();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a Spring config, i'm not using Spring

Answer (score 0):

First of all, enshure that your `DetalleVaPortletBean` object really is constructed by examin the console output and locate the output from 
`System.out.println(this);`

It might be helpul with some more printouts in the constructor, e.g. `System.out.println("DetalleVaPortletBean CTOR");`